# PostgreSQL: Sub-Query on one table

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, inner-join, self-join

My table looks (simplified) like this:

```
ID, File, Subst_ID
1, "AAA"
2, "BBB", 3
3, "CCC"
```

It records filenames "File"; sometimes, a file (here BBB) is replaced by a newer one (here CCC".
First show all records, that have been replaced:

```
SELECT ID, File, Subst_ID FROM Table WHERE Subst_ID IS NOT NULL;
```

OK, brings up line 2. Now I need to add a subquery column QQ, which shows the File of the substitute record, e.g. should bring:

```
2, "BBB", 3, "CCC"
```

. My approach does not work:

```
SELECT ID, File, Subst_ID, (SELECT File FROM Table WHERE Subst-ID = ID) AS QQ FROM Table WHERE Subst_ID IS NOT NULL;
```

Where is my mistake? Thank you!

Comment: Could there be substitutes of substitutes?

Comment: "Does not work" is not a valid Postgres error message.

Comment: Substitute of substitute: Yes BBB now is replaced by CCC, this will never change. But CCC may be replaced next week with DDD.

Comment: Does not work: ... more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Comment: What is the expected output format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a self-join:

```
select t1.*, t2.file as subst_file
from mytable t1
inner join mytable t2 on t2.id = t1.subst_id
```

This is query you wanted to write - I find that is less neat, because it needs a `where` clause, while the above does not:

```
select t1.*,
    (select t2.file from mytable t2 where t2.id = t1.subst_id) as subst_file
from mytable t1
where t1.subst_id is not null
```